# How to set the field label as an <h2>?

Tags: 7, entities

I'd like to be able to set the field label as an `<h2>`. How can I do?

I'm editing the features definition for a field collection directly so if it's possible to set it in there that would be super-handy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can provide a [field.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7) file within the theme.

You can copy the existing field.tpl.php file from /modules/field/theme (which btw is just auxilliary and not used by Drupal) into the theme's directory and replace the line:

`<div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>`

into

`<div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><h2><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</h2></div>`

or something.