# Change Field Label from h2 to div

Tags: 7, theming, commerce

I am looking for days the PHP file which characterizes the Field label with the  tag.
From a certain number of  tags that SEO is technically quite counterproductive.

Can Someone show me how or where to
 Taxonomy Term: 
in
 Taxonomy Term: 
can change?

I found this solution, among other things, but nothing works.
[Change a label element to an <h2>?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83263/change-a-label-element-t)...

Im using Commerce Kickstart 2.39 on AT-Commerce

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you want a fast solution, you might want to look into using Display Suite or Fences... I recommend Display Suite.

https://www.drupal.org/project/ds

It will let you change the label as you want from the admin UI, no file editing needed.

Answer (score 2):

One of the good solutions for you is using [Fences](https://www.drupal.org/project/fences) module,

> Fences is a an easy-to-use tool to specify an HTML element for each
>   field. This element choice will propagate everywhere the field is
>   used, such as teasers, RSS feeds and Views. You don't have to keep
>   re-configuring the same HTML element over and over again every time
>   you display the field.
>
> Best of all, Fences provides leaner markup than Drupal 7 core! And can
>   get rid of the extraneous classes too!

and for learn how you can achieve what you want take a look at:
[Custom Wrappers With Fences Module (Drupal Tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsNqG6DTFTA)